# Is there another way to create a json object using php?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I hope you can help me. Let me explain what im doing:

Im sending a name from a form and making a query to a database named "test", I use $.getJSON to get my json object from a php page but im expectig to be able to create a json obj in a different way.
The part i would like to change is the one of PHP because in that way ill have to assign something for each row like this: " $arreglo->edad = $row["EDAD"]; "
That would be a problem if i had a table with 20 columns or something like that.
Thanks! :)

**HTML**

```
<div class="contenido">
    <div class="principal">
        <form method="get" action="login2.php" id="login">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="usuario">Usuario:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <input type="submit" name="boton" id="boton" value="Enviar">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <div id="contenidos_externos"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#login").submit(function() {
        var datosFormulario = $(this).serialize();
        $.getJSON("login2.php", datosFormulario, procesarDatos);
        return false;
    });

    function procesarDatos(datos_devueltos) {
        $("#contenidos_externos").html("Nombre: " + datos_devueltos.nombre + "<br>Edad: " + datos_devueltos.edad);
    }

});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$conn=null;

if(!$conn){
    try{
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test","root","");
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die("Ha habido un error al conectar con nuestra base de datos, lo sentimos :C. " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}


$el_usuario=isset($_GET['usuario']) ? $_GET['usuario'] : $_POST['usuario'];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE NOMBRE = :nomb";   

$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(":nomb"=>$el_usuario));
$array = $query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$arreglo = new stdClass();

foreach($array as $row){
    $arreglo->nombre = $row["NOMBRE"];
    $arreglo->edad = $row["EDAD"];
}
$json = json_encode($arreglo);
echo $json;


?>
```

Comment: First of all it appears that you are overwriting one and the same object `$arreglo` all the time, for each row. But in general, you could just use `json_encode($array)`... then the columns would have their original upper-case names though. If you need them lower-case you would need to iterate over all rows and fields and convert them.

Comment: Hey CherryDT, thanks a lot for the answer but...                                                 I have tried what you say, and when i try to for example do this: $("#contenidos_externos").html("Nombre: " + datos_devueltos.NOMBRE); i get undefined instead of the value... :(

Comment: Well, you have an array of results, not one... e.g. `datos_devueltos[0].NOMBRE` for the first, `datos_devueltos[1].NOMBRE` for the second, etc. - if you want to fetch just one, then why do you use `fetchAll` in the first place? You should use `$query->fetch` instead...

Comment: That is what i was talking about, thank you a lot! You are a genius!!